# Retrieving attribute from XML file in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve an attribute from an XML file in Microsoft SQL Server. My query works for fetching the elements but not for the attributes.

This is a part of the XML:

```
<DN_CHARGE_LINES>
        <DN_CHARGE_LINE LINE_ID="201903297661150">
            <CHARGE_NAME>HANDLING CHARGE</CHARGE_NAME>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <RATE>75</RATE>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <LINE_AMOUNT>75</LINE_AMOUNT>
            <JOB_ID>201903137354913</JOB_ID>
        </DN_CHARGE_LINE>
    </DN_CHARGE_LINES>
```

Here is the code which I am currently using:

```
INSERT INTO WWL_DNHead (DN_ID, TO_PARTY_NAME, TO_PARTY_ADDRESS)
SELECT 
       MY_XML.DN_HEAD.query('@DN_ID').value('.', 'VARCHAR(25)'),
       MY_XML.DN_HEAD.query('TO_PARTY_NAME').value('.', 'VARCHAR(25)'),
       MY_XML.DN_HEAD.query('TO_PARTY_ADDRESS').value('.', 'VARCHAR(25)')


FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
     FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\shareapp\c$\temp\XML_4\DN_DN1903297826.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
     CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('WWLDCEDI/DN_HEAD') AS MY_XML (DN_HEAD)

     SELECT * FROM WWL_DNHead
```

I would like to retrieve the `LINE_ID` and display it in an SQL table in addition to `CHARGE_NAME`, `CURRENCY_CODE` and all the other elements from that node (which I am able to fetch right now).

Comment: The xml you posted does not match the query (you're using different names).

Comment: question not clear but as per my understanding. are you looking for something like `MY_XML.DN_HEAD.value('(./*/@LINE_ID)[1]','varchar(40)')`

Comment: LINE_ID and DN_ID are the same kinds of an attribute and I have tried your solution but it also gives me the following error: "XQuery [T.MY_XML.query()]: Attribute may not appear outside of an element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nodes` to split your XML at element value and then `value` to extract the values you need:

```
declare @table table (MY_XML xml)

insert into @table select
'<DN_CHARGE_LINES>
    <DN_CHARGE_LINE LINE_ID="201903297661150">
        <CHARGE_NAME>HANDLING CHARGE</CHARGE_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <RATE>75</RATE>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
        <LINE_AMOUNT>75</LINE_AMOUNT>
        <JOB_ID>201903137354913</JOB_ID>
    </DN_CHARGE_LINE>
</DN_CHARGE_LINES>'

select  
     cn.s.value('@LINE_ID'        , 'nvarchar(max)') AS LINE_ID
    ,cn.s.value('CHARGE_NAME[1]'  , 'nvarchar(max)') AS CHARGE_NAME
    ,cn.s.value('CURRENCY_CODE[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS CURRENCY_CODE
    ,cn.s.value('RATE[1]'         , 'nvarchar(max)') AS RATE
    ,cn.s.value('QTY[1]'          , 'nvarchar(max)') AS QTY
    ,cn.s.value('JOB_ID[1]'       , 'nvarchar(max)') AS JOB_ID
from @table
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('//DN_CHARGE_LINE') cn(s)
```

result:

[image]

If you have more `<DN_CHARGE_LINE>` elements:

```
declare @table table (MY_XML xml)

insert into @table select
'<DN_CHARGE_LINES>
    <DN_CHARGE_LINE LINE_ID="201903297661150">
        <CHARGE_NAME>HANDLING CHARGE</CHARGE_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <RATE>75</RATE>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
        <LINE_AMOUNT>75</LINE_AMOUNT>
        <JOB_ID>201903137354913</JOB_ID>
    </DN_CHARGE_LINE>
    <DN_CHARGE_LINE LINE_ID="123123123123123">
        <CHARGE_NAME>HANDLING CHARGE 2</CHARGE_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>EUR</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <RATE>100</RATE>
        <QTY>2</QTY>
        <LINE_AMOUNT>10</LINE_AMOUNT>
        <JOB_ID>201903137565987</JOB_ID>
    </DN_CHARGE_LINE>
    <DN_CHARGE_LINE LINE_ID="123456789123456">
        <CHARGE_NAME>HANDLING CHARGE 3</CHARGE_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <RATE>3</RATE>
        <QTY>4</QTY>
        <LINE_AMOUNT>30</LINE_AMOUNT>
        <JOB_ID>201903137111222</JOB_ID>
    </DN_CHARGE_LINE>
</DN_CHARGE_LINES>'

select  
     cn.s.value('@LINE_ID'        , 'nvarchar(max)') AS LINE_ID
    ,cn.s.value('CHARGE_NAME[1]'  , 'nvarchar(max)') AS CHARGE_NAME
    ,cn.s.value('CURRENCY_CODE[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS CURRENCY_CODE
    ,cn.s.value('RATE[1]'         , 'nvarchar(max)') AS RATE
    ,cn.s.value('QTY[1]'          , 'nvarchar(max)') AS QTY
    ,cn.s.value('JOB_ID[1]'       , 'nvarchar(max)') AS JOB_ID
from @table
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('//DN_CHARGE_LINE') cn(s)
```

this is the result:

[image]